# CSS Vertical align middle

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align a SPAN element in the middle of a parent element.

This is what I am doing:

[image]

I am trying to get both the username and password labels to be vertically aligned (middle) with the input boxes.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="login_field_wrap">
    <span>Username</span>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" id="username" name="username">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
.clear { clear:both; }
.login_field_wrap span {
float:left; vertical-align:middle; font-size:13px; color:#333; font-weight:bold; }
.login_field_wrap input {
float:right; vertical-align:middle; padding:8px 5px; border:solid 1px #AAA;
margin:0px; width:250px; }
```

Vertically aligning an image element inside of this wrapping DIV works absolutely fine, well in Chrome anyway, it just won't align with my SPAN!

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Please be nice to your users and rather than a generic `<span>`, use a label that is explicitly associated with the form control: `<label for="username">Username</label>`.

Comment: @steveax: I always use labels for checkboxes and radio buttons due to their smaller size. Using a label obviously increases the clickable area making it easier for them to use, but is it really necessary to provide a label for a text box that is 250px x 30px? When browsing the internet myself, I have never clicked on a textbox's label to focus on it. Is there another reason why I should be using a label?

Comment: Increasing the hit area is just one benefit of using labels, the other important reason is for screenreader users. By explicitly associating the labels with the form controls the screenreader will read the labels properly when the form control is focused.

Comment: Okay, that's worth reading about. Thanks for your comment @steveax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vertical aligning via CSS can be tricky, and while CSS3 brings about a slew of goodies to help with that, CSS3 support is lackluster in the current browser market.

To achieve this effect I set the `line-height` property of the child element equal to the height of its containing element.

For example, I would use the following CSS:

```
.login_field_wrap { height:30px; /* or whatever is appropriate for your design */
.login_field_wrap span { height:30px; line-height:30px; }
.login_field_wrap input { height:30px; line-height:30px; }
```

The only downside of using `line-height` to vertically align something is if the text overflows onto a second line, in which case your design will essentially break.

Comment: This works great, but people should know that if the parent element changes size dynamically the alignment will mess up (or at least stay within the predefined `line-height: 30px`). If it does change, then you should consider using the table display method. Either way, there does need to be a better way of vertically aligning relevant inline elements. Great answer @Moses.

Answer (score 9):

Just remove the `float` property from your span class and set it to `display:inline-block` and the `vertical-align:middle` property will work, like so:

```
.login_field_wrap span {
    color: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Edit: cleaned up your code a bit, here is a demo that should work across browsers.
http://jsfiddle.net/kUe3Y/

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to do this is to set the parent container display property to `table` and the child display property to `table-cell`

```
#parent{
  display:table;
}

#child{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I was able to get this to vertically align an anchor element inside a div.

I put it into the terms of your question in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD2nM/).

Answer (score 1):

I have never been able to get `vertical-align` to work in anything other than <td>s. 
A workaround I commonly use would be to define a height for `.login_field_wrap`, then set the `line-height` property in your <span> to be equal to `.login_field_wrap`'s height.

Comment: Tricky, huh?! I managed to get an image element to vertically align (middle) inside a wrapping DIV but it just won't do it with the span!!

Answer (score -4):

I think text-align:center; should work on elements too. If I am not mistaken, that usually works even if not on text.

Comment: Text-align set to center horizontally aligns text and some elements. I am looking for vertical alignment set to middle as the question title says. Thanks for making the effort, regardless.